# PHP Clear "reply-to:" for mail

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

Example:

```
email 1 has email to reply to as `test@testing.co.uk`
email 2 has email to reply to as `support@testing.co.uk`
```

My current code:

```
if($this->teacherEmail && $this->teacher_reply_enable)
    $this->mail->AddReplyTo($this->teacherEmail, $this->schoolTitle);
else 
    $this->mail->AddReplyTo($this->schoolEmail, $this->schoolTitle);

$this->mail->Subject = $this->subject;
$this->mail->msgHTML($this->getMessage());
$this->mail->AltBody = strip_tags($this->message);
$this->mail->addAddress($this->to, $this->to_name);         
foreach($this->attachments as $item){   
    $email_attachment = DOC_ROOT.$item->path.$item->orig;
    $email_attachment_title = $item->name;
    $this->mail->addAttachment($email_attachment,$email_attachment_title);
}
if (!$this->mail->send()) {
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
```

The problem i'm having is that email 1 has been sent successfully the `reply-to:` is test@testing.co.uk, then email 2 is sent and the `reply-to:` is both `test@testing.co.uk` and `support@testing.co.uk`.

I want it to reset the `reply-to:` for each email sent so that it doesn't have the issue of having two `reply-to:`'s

Comment: What is the problem if it get stored?

Comment: If you're sending to a list, you might like to look at the [mailing list example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps) provided with PHPMailer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation there is a method called [clearReplyTos](http://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.html#method_clearReplyTos). You could try calling that first as below:

```
$this->mail->clearReplyTos();
if($this->teacherEmail && $this->teacher_reply_enable)
    $this->mail->AddReplyTo($this->teacherEmail, $this->schoolTitle);
else 
    $this->mail->AddReplyTo($this->schoolEmail, $this->schoolTitle);
```

I haven't used it myself but just a quick skim of the doc pages brought that up.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted Peter! Thank you very much for the quick reply.

Comment: You're welcome! Glad it worked and that I could help.